# JSF Hosting for testing

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jsf, tomcat, jsf-2

i just finish a web application with JSF 2.2, Hibernate 4.3, Primefaces 5.0, Tomcat 7.0.65 and MySQL 5.7.

i want to know if there any free host to try the result (i try it on localhost, works good) but i want to try it in web.

i try it in openshift but doesn't work (don't know exactly the issue).
and i tested on jelastic but not working, i found an error in tomcat log (... not support `selectOneMenuView`)

any idea, suggestion ?

maybe with a plan hosting for only one month (just for testing) and not expensive, it can be helpful/option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your original question: Jelastic is probably the best "out of box" option. CloudBees has a Java EE 7 offering as well. If you want a more DIY solution, setup a TomEE, WildFly, or Payara server on DigitalOcean.

If you would like help solving the problem, post information about your localhost environment, the actual piece of code that isn't working, and the stack trace and we'll be able to pinpoint what's not working. Usually "not found" and "not supported" errors indicate something wrong with you Maven build.